# html/css h3 and p tag on one row

Tags: html, css

I have this html code

```
<h3>City </h3><p>London</p>
```

and this is my css

```
.details>h3{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px 0 15px 0;
}
.details>p{
    color: #a0a0a0;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

But the text is on two rows
[image]

I want to City and the name of the city to be on 1 row.
How to make it to look like this?
[image]

How to make it to look like this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `h3` and `p` are by default block-level elements. Means they have by default a width of 100%. As such they are displayed below each other.

The easiest way to display them next to each other is to convert them to an inline-element with `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`.

```css
h3, p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h3>City </h3><p>London</p>
```

Alternatively, you can align block-level elements next to each other with a parent that has `display: flex`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<h3>City </h3><p>London</p>
```

Note, that `h3` is a tag for headlines and should only be used for that (Semantical correctness => accessibiltiy => improved SEO rating). If you want to display an element bold and larger use `font-size` and `font-weight` instead!

```css
span {
  font-size: 1.17em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p><span>City </span>London</p>
```